# Authentification method

Tags: java, sql

I created a login class but I still have a null point of exception error message and I can not get to know his source help me please, this is my code and message error

```
public boolean Authentification(String user, String password){
boolean result=false;
try {

conn=con.Connect();

stmt = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet  rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from login  where user ='"+user+"' AND password='"+password+"'"); 

if ( rs.next()) 
result=true;
stmt.close();

conn.close();


}  catch (SQLException e) { 
e.printStackTrace();
}
return result;

}
```

call methode

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
                // TODO add your handling code here:
                System.out.println("user"+user.getText()+" pass "+password.getText());
                boolean Login =m.Authentification(user.getText(), password.getText());
            }
```

error message

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Interfaces.Authentification.jButton1ActionPerformed(Authentification.java:215)
    at Interfaces.Authentification.access$100(Authentification.java:21)
    at Interfaces.Authentification$2.actionPerformed(Authentification.java:84)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
```

Comment: Are you getting user,password?

Comment: yes of corse, my print get result without problem

Comment: Then its look like your method having the issue.learn java coding standards your variable ,method declarations are not correct

Comment: what is m.Authentification(user.getText(), password.getText());? check that whether that giving issue else share full code.

Comment: Where is your m declared? Seems that it is null.

Comment: m its instance of class where locate my method authentification

Comment: show code with m declaration and initialization

Comment: I found my error,i fourget the new